# Limit construction tools listed for an edit template to custom edit tool

Tags: arcobjects

Is it possible to limit the construction tools available for a specific feature class to a custom edit tool?  I'm porting a 9.3 extension to 10, and would like to move tools off an old toolbar and into the Construction Tools panel.  I've ported one tool over.  However, I want the tool to only show when the feature class it is inteded to work with is set as the current edit template.  In addition, I want to hide the standard construction tools that are available.

The feature class has a class extension associated with it.  I've been able to use the ClassID within the IEditEvents5.OnCurrentTemplateChanged event to determine if the current edit template is the correct feature class.  But all I can do with the tool is enable it or disable it.  I want to be able to hide the custom tool all together for all other feature classes.  In addition, I want to hide the standard tools that are displayed as well, limiting the users options to just the custom edit tool.

If I can't make this work I'll just go back to placing the tools on a toolbar again, but I would like to be able to intergrate the tools into the native editing environment if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word from ESRI is that this is not currently possible.  The best you can do is change the edit template tool to the custom tool at the time the template is selected.  It may be something that is available in a later release.